# Difference between File and ::File in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have come across two methods of calling a file class: `File` and `::File`

Can someone explain to me the difference between the two, and also the separate reasons for using the two?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`File` refers to the `File` constant in the current scope, while `::File` always refers to `Object::File`.

```
p File
# File

p ::File
# File

module Another
  module File
  end

  p File
  # Another::File

  p ::File
  # File
end
```

Thus, the `::` is analogous to the root of a file system and the module you are in is analogous to the current directory.

For object-oriented access to the current lexical scope, see [Module.nesting](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-c-nesting).

Answer (score 2):

When you reference a class with a short name (`File`), ruby will use a class from the closest scope. Look:

```
module MyModule
  class File
    def initialize *args; end
  end

  class Foo
    def initialize
      @file = File.new
    end
    attr_accessor :file
  end
end


f = MyModule::Foo.new
f.file.class # => MyModule::File

file2 = File.new 'newfile', 'w'
file2.class # => File
```

So, `Foo` sees different `File` than the code on the top level. However, if `Foo` were to use this code:

```
@file = ::File.new
```

Then it would use "global" `File` class, not local to `MyModule`. In a similar fashion we can use `MyModule::File` on the top level

```
file2 = MyModule::File.new 'newfile', 'w'
```