# what does ::Class in ruby do?

Tags: ruby

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is Ruby’s double-colon (::) all about?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3009477/what-is-rubys-double-colon-all-about)

pardon for my laziness. I tried to guess. I am not sure what the double '::Logger' does in this case?

https://github.com/wycats/rack-offline/blob/master/lib/rack/offline.rb#L25

it seems like it is initializing the object and assign it on a variable that is not in its scope? line 25 is wrapped by {begin/end} block and gets assigned to @logger

Comment: `::Logger` is referencing `Logger` class from top level namespace.

Comment: [We answered this very question yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14271860/512904).

Comment: @MatheusMoreira: yes, indeed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like a `/` in a path defines nested directories, `::` accesses nested classes.

And also similarly to a leading `/`, a leading `::` means to start at the the very top of the tree. It starts searching for constants at the global scope.

```
# Bar declared in global scope
class Bar
end

# Foo declared in global scope    
class Foo

  # A different class named Bar declared in the scope of Foo, not global
  class Bar
  end

  Bar   #=> refers to Foo::Bar, that is class Bar declared within Foo
  ::Bar #=> refers to outer global scope class named Bar

end
```